# Proper way to hide .php extension while building an Application

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hide

For the last Website Project (A Basic Website with a AJAX + PHP Contact Form),  I have used the below `.htaccess` file to hide the Extension. It worked perfectly on the Hostgator Server.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Now I am going to build a new Application (***Functional & Dynamic***). I copied the `.htaccess` file to my localhost/appfolder/ (WAMPserver). Also enabled `rewrite_module`. However it doesn't work for some reason on the localhost.

Check the error message which I obtained while I try to run the Same Website on localhost with above `.htaccess` (***Runs on Live Server but not on localhost***)

```
**Not Found**

    The requested URL /services.php was not found on this server.

    Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Should I be adding be something or am I doing it wrong. **What is the proper way to achieve that. How do you guys do it**?

Comment: The proper way to hide extensions, IMO create all the URLs without extensions. and redirect page to desired location through htaccess. www.mysite/login etc

Comment: can you explain how to rewrite the .htaccess to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work on a sub-directory `appfolder` you need to replace:

```
RewriteBase /
```

by

```
RewriteBase /appfolder/
```

Otherwise shown code will try to find any `.php` file in root of the site.

Comment: ok Good now it works.. But currently I'am giving href links as example.php. The Rewrite method works great ie shows only example... But when I hover the cursor over Menu Links, it shows example.php.

What is the proper way of making links. and what edit should be made to .htaccess for that

Comment: No .htaccess rule cam make changes in your HTML source. If you want hover to reflect right link then you should modify your HTML to use `href="/appfolder/example"`

Comment: can you explain how to rewrite the .htaccess to achieve that( ie directing to corresponding php page)

Comment: You already have those rules shown in your question. Only change required was `RewriteBase /appfolder/`